# Git: Cannot pull branch back into local (Couldn't find remote ref)

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I'm new to git and am really struggling with it. Recently I created a new branch, did some work, and pushed it up to GitHub, creating a pull request. No issues there.

However, my local work development environment got updated and I lost all local references to my branches. I need to get my work back on my local so I continue.

From reading online, I have tried:

Recreating my branch:

`git checkout -b 'name-of-branch-I-had-been-working-on'`

Pull in branch from remote

`git pull origin 'name-of-branch-I-had-been-working-on'`

I then tried removing the local branch I created above (`git branch -d`) and tried:

`git fetch origin 'name-of-branch-I-had-been-working-on'`

but in each occasion I get the error:

`fatal: Couldn't find remote ref name-of-branch-I-had-been-working-on`

Would anyone know the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does the branch you want to recover from remote appear in the list when you do a `git branch -r` ? If not, I'm afraid it's lost. If it does, just delete your local branch, fetch again for remote references and checkout your branch without the *remote/* at start of the name

Comment: @RomainVALERI Yes it does

Comment: Depending on exactly what happened to your local repository, you might be able to get the commit back from `git reflog`

Answer (score 2):

From comments : 
Me : Does the branch you want to recover from remote appear in the list when you do a `git branch -r` ?
You : yes it does.

From this point I would :
(if needed, first stash any uncommited changes)

```
# first delete the failed new branch
git branch -D local-branch-you-just-created-when-trying-to-solve-the-problem
# get all up-to-date remote references into your local repo
git fetch
# (optionnally) list all branches to be sure
git branch -a
# to avoid typos, copy-paste the line with your branch in your next checkout
# which will recreate a local version of said remote branch
git checkout name-of-the-branch-you-try-to-recover-from-remote
```

Note : when all branches are listed (let's say your branch is named "feature_A"), don't

```
git checkout origin/feature_A
```

(which checkout the *remote-tracking* branch) but instead just

```
git checkout feature_A
```

for the local instance.

Comment: I'm afraid that just gives me the same error as above

Comment: @MeltingDog You mean you have the same fatal error ? When checking out a copied-and-pasted branch name taken from a fresh `git branch -a` ? That's weird. I wonder if there could be some misunderstanding on another element of the problem.

Comment: Yep same fatal error. Yeah could quite possibly be a misunderstanding I've made along the way. Git is a huge chasm of knowledge for me and it seems tutorials differ so much from reality it's impossible to learn

Answer (score 1):

What I recommend you to execute is the following:
1. Open git bash in the required location
2. Clone remote repo to local pc: `git clone <repo_url>`
3. In order to list all remote branches: `git branch -a`
   The green line represents the branch that you are in. The red that are starting with remotes/ are possible remote branches to move to.
4. To checkout to remote branch: `git checkout <branch_name>`

That's it basically :) now work on the branch... commit your changes and once you want to push your changes run: `git push origin <branch_name>`

Comment: If I may, why the cloning step ?

Comment: mmm I was trying to give explanation end-to-end for the given issue. So in this case the user said that his pc environment was changed... so as I see it, first step is cloning the repo from remote :) and after that you can start dealing with branches :)